# MATLAB - Increasing spacing between x-axis points (non-uniform plotting) other than logarithmic

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to increase spacing between x-axis points so that, for example in the plot below, the distance between 10 30 increases and the distance between 1150 and 1300 decreases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer to new question (distorting the x-axis field to affect points):

Unfortunately my research shows no built-in way to do this in MATLAB. I see others suggesting:

1. Distorting the field in your own data, *e.g.* change x-value from 10, 30, and 50 to 100, 300, and 500 to get 10x magnification, then add 500 to all other x-values so they shift to the right; and then modifying the labels (see below) to read "10", "30", "50", "100", etc.
2. Using a histogram, where your x-axis labels become bins, *e.g.* 10, 30, 50, 100, etc. and you use empty bins to space the points.

#### Answer to old question (affecting x-axis labels and ticks, not points):

From the [MathWorks docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), it appears you can arbitrarily set the tick locations, whether uniform or not:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = [-3*pi -2*pi -pi 0 pi 2*pi 3*pi];
ax.YTick = [-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1];

% For R2014a and earlier:
% ax = gca;
% set(ax,'XTick',[-3*pi -2*pi -pi 0 pi 2*pi 3*pi])
% set(ax,'YTick',[-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1])
```

So, write a function that creates the spacing you desire and assign its return to `XTick`. In your case, it looks like you just need to retrieve the domain values of the points you want to plot.

Comment: thanks but i think i can not explain my mind. I want for example from image that attached, space between 1150 and 1300 decrease and space between 10 and 50 increase.

Comment: Hm. If you want to increase spacing between your x-axis _labels_, then I've already given you the solution. You just need to do `ax.XTick = [100 200 300 400 500 700 850 1000 1150 1300]`. Derive those from the domains of your points, if you wish. If instead you mean you wish to distort your x-axis _field_ so that your points are in different places, then I think you need to say so in your question. Is it about your labels or your points?

Comment: i want to change space between points. so that for example as i said from image that attached, space between 1150 and 1300 decrease and space between 10 and 50 increase . also i edit my question.

Comment: @martin - I've edited your question and my answer. Unfortunately, no pretty solution appears to exist.